# How to maintain static reference data in Rest API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, api-design, static-data

I've been developing REST API using springboot and came across situation like API needs to maintain some reference data table eg : consumer will request with a particular key and that key will be interpreted inside the API by looking up reference data my question is from below methods which are the best way to handle this if none of these proper methods what are the suggested ways.

1. Have reference data in the database as a key-value pairs - modification is cons
2. Have it inside the project as an XML data file - not centralized modification on multiple places 
   3.Have it inside the JVM as the static data load on app bootstrap

further, this is open for you all to suggest me any additional ways or most optimum way

Comment: Does the choice of how to maintain the static data have anything to do with this being a REST API?

Comment: Well the short answer is no, the reason I briefed the api context because anyone looking at this can give an answer   keeping API context in mind